# I want to render controller/action inside a div in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

Lets say I have a 300X300px block called "Statistics" or "Friends" this block requires some database objects and logical operations that traditionally should be placed inside a controller, which prepares some instance variables that will be displayed nicely in it's view/partial.

This block could be called from many pages in my website, crossing various controllers and actions.

How can I go about this problem without repeating code inside controllers, nor placing logic inside views.

A bad solution would be to place SQL queries inside views, or using iframes where a single controller/action generates the expected HTML.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the kind of thing you should do in a helper method. It might be a good idea to use `locals` for you partial instead of instance variables so as not to pollute the namespace of your views:

```rb
module ApplicatonHelper

  def friends_block
    friends = Friend.where(...)
    # Assuming the 'friends_block' partial is in a directory 'app/views/shared'
    render :partial => "shared/friends_block", :locals => {:friends => friends}  
  end

end
```

The `friends_block` partial would use the local variable:

```
<div id="friends_block">
  <% friends.each do |s| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And other views would just use the helper method without having to worry about anything else:

```
<%= friends_block %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Cells gem:
https://github.com/apotonick/cells

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the block into a partial and ensure that the required instance variables for that block are loaded in a `before_filter` on the relevant controllers and actions.